# How to create excel kind of filter, sorting, edit data in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, filter, edit, paging

I want to allow 20k data records in asp.net to filter, sort, paging and edit. Which is the best possible?

Comment: Hi Ankita, this package may meet your needs https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/. With this package, you can read data from the .xls, .xlsx file into your application for more operations.

Comment: He says nothing about importing, or working with Excel data. he wants a grid like display similar to excel - not that he is working with Excel. So how to create a Excel like interface or display with filters, sorting that looks similar to Excel is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as noted, we can't load 20k records at one time - that would be too much data for a use at one time.

So, can you add paging and say display a screen of data in grid/table like view? yes, that's easy.

Can you add sorting to the grid display (say sort up/down) Yes, it will take a wee bit of code, but that can be done quite easy.

But to allow say the user to filter on any column? Hum, that going to take quite a bit of work. So you can certainly acheive the first two goals - quite easy.

but there not any built in filter system + set of controls that will acheive the filtering options for you. I REALLY wish there was. You can consider some 3rd party controls - they are quite expensive, but they do look very nice. So, say this grid from telerick is a great example of what you looking for:

[image]

So the above has paging, and sorting, and filters.

demo here:
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

I REALLY don't know why after all these years that the base .net package does not include a grid extender or a listview control that is so feature starved, that everyone every day has to go out and re-invent the world.

But then you have to work to add a data pager And out of the box, the default format for the pager does not look all that great. Once you spend a hour or two, you can get a nice formatted data pager (but it should not be that much work to get a nice look and feel out of the box - it just should not be).

So say here is a listview (I used the wizards - then deleted 99% of the markup, and with this markup:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:label ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:label ID="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                    <th runat="server">Active</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

So the listview is a nice way to present the data.

However, to get a nice layout, nice filtering, a half decent looking datapager? It takes a truckload of work. The out of the box asp.net controls used to be perhaps the BEST feature of asp.net

That above page was created by me in less time to write this post. It looks not bad - but "not bad" was 5 or 10 years ago.

The new data controls out of the box should be like the first grid - the amounts of efforts to obtain a nice looking grid IMHO is just not all that great right now.

So, I would consider a 3rd party grid control, or you going to have to learn quite a bit of css to get a great looking Excel like display.

It is possible. My beters would be for simple - gridview.

But, for really nice layout - extra options - go with listview - it requires  a bit more markup, but has near unlimited flexbility.